# Getting an MD5 of a remote file blob in Azure node js SDK

Tags: javascript, node.js, azure, azure-blob-storage

I'm writing a backup script that will pull a full copy of every file in a specific blob container in our Windows Azure blob storage. These files are not uploaded by me, I'm just writing a script that traverses the blob storage and downloads the files.
To speed up this process and skip unnecessary downloads, I'd like to request MD5s for the files before downloading them, and compare them with the already local files.

My problem: I can't find documentation anywhere detailing how to do this. I'm pretty sure the API supports it, I'm finding docs and answered questions related to other languages everywhere, but not for the Node.js Azure SDK.

My question: Is it possible, and if yes, how, to request an MD5 for the remote file blob through the Azure Node.js SDK, before downloading it? And is it faster than just downloading the file?

Comment: The Azure API doesn't define MD5 support because hashing is part of Node's core API. http://nodejs.org/api/crypto.html. Specifically, `crypto.createHash()`.

Comment: @JonathanLonowski That's for the client side, I want to retrieve a hash for the blob on the server side, without downloading the blob. Afaik there should be MD5 metadata available for the serverside blobs, I've seen it in REST, Java and C# examples already.

Comment: That is, I want to retrieve the MD5 for the serverside blob, on the client, to compare with the local file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is certainly possible to get blob's `MD5` hash. When you list blobs, you'll get MD5 in blob's properties. See the sample code below:

```
var azure = require('azure');
var blobService = azure.createBlobService("accountname", "accountkey");

blobService.listBlobs("containername", function(error, blobs){
    if(!error){
        for(var index in blobs){
            console.log(blobs[index].name );
            console.log(blobs[index].properties['content-md5'] );
        }
    }
});
```

Obviously the catch is that blob should have this property set. If this property is not set, then an empty string is returned.

Comment: My hero! This is exactly what I was looking for! And whaddya know, the blobs have been properly uploaded with MD5 set! Been looking for this all day, how did you find this? The Windows Azure docs are rather.. barebone, I could only find howto guides and such.

Comment: Thank you (blushing :))! Not sure if you know this but the source code is for node.js SDK is available on Github: https://github.com/WindowsAzure/azure-sdk-for-node/. Just hacked some code using 'How To guide' here: http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/nodejs/how-to-guides/blob-storage/#list-blob.